# Class attribute returning Empty

Tags: python-3.x

I created a class and initialized the attribute in the **init** method. I am updating the class attribute in the methods. After I created the object and trying the print the class attribute, it is returning empty. Please tell me where it is going wrong.

```
     class Counter(object):
            def __init__(self, start=1):
                self.val = start
                self.params = {}

            def increment(self):
                self.val += 1
                self.params['name'] = 'sameer'
                self.params['age'] = 26
                return

            def decrement(self):
                self.val -= 1
                return
 c = Counter()
 print(c.params)

Output:
{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only populate your `.params` dict in the `increment()` method and never call this method, so obviously it stays empty. Just call `c.increment()` and re-print `c.params`.

As a side note:

> I am updating the **class attribute** (...) trying the print the **class attribute** (...)

In your example, `params` is an **instance** attribute (each instance has it's own `param` dict), not a "class attribute". In Python, a "class attribute" is an attribute that belongs to the class itself and is shared amongst all instances of the class, ie:

```
class Foo(object):
    shared = [] # this is a class attribute

    def __init__(self):
        self.owned = [] # this is an instance attribute
```